supabase.auth.signInWithOtp() doesn't resolve
I have a simple magic email link process for new users, that calls supabase.auth.signInWithOtp. The process works fine (it sends the mail, and generates a magic link)- but this function never seems to resolve - so I can't get the response or trigger anything to say "Now check your mail!".

import { ref } from 'vue'
import { supabase } from '../supabase.js';

const email = ref(''); // bound to an input field in the template
const sent_magic_link = ref(false);

const signInOrRegisterViaMagicLink = async () => {

  try {


    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOtp({
      email: email.value
    });
    if (error !== undefined) throw error;

// this bit never executes - even if the magic link is sent correctly.
    console.log('do something with', data);
    sent_magic_link.value = true;

  } catch (error) {
    if(error instanceof Error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  }
}

In the network panel, I can see the request has completed with a 200 status... What am I missing? I expect to get (as per docs) an object like:
{
  "data": {
    "user": null,
    "session": null
  },
  "error": null
}

NB I'm working in the local dev environment - might that be a factor?
